# jQuery simple hint not always working

Tags: jquery

I got this code for hints:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#accept').hide();
    $('#error').hide();
});

function newnick(){
    var newnick = $('#newnick').val();
    if(newnick.match(/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        // THIS ISN'T WORKING:
        var scrol = $(document).scrollTop() + 10;
        $("#error").css({'margin-top':scrol + 'px'})
        $("#error").html("Nope");
        $("#error").show();
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'doedit.php',
        data: {mach: "username", username: newnick},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == 0)
            {
                // BUT THIS WORKS:
                var scrol = $(document).scrollTop() + 10;
                $("#error").css({'margin-top':scrol + 'px'})
                $("#error").html("Dieser nickname ist bereits vergeben!");
                $("#error").show();
            }
            else
            {
                // AND THIS WORKS:
                var scrol = $(document).scrollTop() + 10;
                $("#accept").css({'margin-top':scrol + 'px'})
                $("#accept").html("Nickname gespeichert");
                $("#accept").show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see I use it multiple times but it works only in AJAX because I also tested it this way:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#accept').hide();
    $('#error').hide();
});

function newnick(){
        var scrol = $(document).scrollTop() + 10;
        $("#error").css({'margin-top':scrol + 'px'})
        $("#error").html("Nope");
        $("#error").show();
}
```

and it's not working.

When I remove:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#accept').hide();
    $('#error').hide();
});
```

Then the hint shows up but I can't click it away ofc. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As javascript is asynchronous, the function `$(document).click(function(){});` will not always be called before the function `newnick()`.

If the function `show()` is called before the function `hide()`, "error" will be hidden. As the AJAX function takes longer, the function `show()` will most likely be called after the function `$(document).click(function(){});`.

So basically, you have to wait for the function `$(document).click(function(){});` to finish before calling the function `newnick()`

Comment: But how can I fix this? tried to put $(document).click(function() {
    $('#accept').hide();
    $('#error').hide();
}); at the top and $(document).ready(function() { before the newnick function